# Is there a standard name for the functions $f(x) = |x|^q$?

Tags: functions, special-functions

Do the following sets of functions have common/standard names?

- $f(x) = |x|^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (or $\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$)
- $f(x) = |x|^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$
- $f(x) = |x|^r$ for $r \in \mathbb{R}$

For example, the functions $f(x) = r^x$ are usually called the exponential functions.

Comment: I believe you missed the absolute value symbols; the function is $|x|^r$, not $x^r$.

Comment: I only meant to point out that you aren't changing any values in the end; you're only extending the function to new values.  But this doesn't really answer your question in any way (and was not immediately clear), so I removed the comment.  I don't think I've seen a term for these functions, though I'd probably call them "absolute power functions" (but some other places use a slightly different meaning than your definitions, where the absolute power of $x,y$ is $|x|^n$, where $n$ is the integer part of $y$)